# Unir dois IF ou mais

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select, union

Preciso unir alguns `if`'s e estou com dificuldades,

Já tentei utilizar com o `union`, porém sem sucesso.

A query que estou executando é:

---

```
IF (select count(Estado)

  FROM tbl_1
    where Estado != 'WIP' AND Estado !='on hold') > 0

    BEGIN
    SELECT 'Estado NOK: ', Nome, (Estado), SLA from tbl_1 
    where (Estado != 'WIP' AND Estado !='on hold')

    END

ELSE
    BEGIN
    SELECT 'Estado OK'

    END 


----------


//e o outro if seria:


----------


IF (select count(SLA) 

    FROM tbl_1
        where SLA != '24x7' AND SLA != '10x8') >0

    BEGIN
    SELECT 'Dados NOK: ', Nome, Estado, (SLA) from tbl_1 
    where (SLA != '24x7' AND SLA != '10x8')

    END

ELSE
    BEGIN
    SELECT 'Dados OK' 

    END
```

---

O que preciso é que essas duas querys sejam unidas em uma só.

Comment: Qual o SGBD? Parece ser SQLServer, estou certo?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Jefferson

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando um sql dinâmico:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = ''

IF (/*CONDICAO 1*/)
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'PESQUISA TRUE '
END
ELSE
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'PESQUISA FALSE '

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'UNION '

IF (/*CONDICAO 2*/)
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'PESQUISA TRUE '
END
ELSE
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'PESQUISA FALSE '

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Mas para utilizar o union as duas pesquisas, quando der verdadeiro ou falso, devem retornar o mesmo número de colunas.